# Nodejs websocket and https using same port

Tags: node.js, https, websocket, reverse-proxy

Inside an embedded linux machine, I have a php restful api running on Lighttpd webserver that serve pages, images and all Angular.io application bundles.
This webserver use the standard https 443 port.

Now for a notification feature, I have implemented a NodeJs script (running on the same embedded machine) that creates a secure websocket  listening connection using a different port  8181.

My Angular.io application, works fine and receive notifications correctly from the websocket. 
When I put my embedded machine in a public network the websocket port can obviously be blocked and I can't receive notifications incoming from 8181.

The question is, how can I modify my sctructure to handle this scenario?
Can my node script listen to 443 standard port for the notification websocket and also pipe requests and response (for pages, images, js, css...etc etc) to lightppd server running in a different local port?

```
var server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync( '/etc/lighttpd/certs/lighttpd.pem' ),
    cert: fs.readFileSync( '/etc/lighttpd/certs/lighttpd.pem' )        
},
function(request, response) {
    /* can i pipe from here to internal lighttpd server port ?*/
});
server.listen(443, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 443');
});

/* the websocket */
wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,        
    autoAcceptConnections: false
});
```

Comment: I don't know all the specific libraries you are using or why PHP is even mentioned here, but the concept can be done where a webSocket server listens for incoming connections using the same server as your web server.  The webSocket protocol is explicitly designed so one can do exactly that and it's done that way for the exact reason you are concerned about (ports other than 80/443 being blocked).  And, it's definitely possible with a node.js https server and `WebSocketServer`.